# How do I return a sequence in Swift?

Tags: generics, dictionary, generator, swift, for-in-loop

I'm trying to write an extension for the `Matrix` example from the book, [slightly tweaked to be generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24136604/458193).
I'm trying to write a method called `getRow` that returns a sequence of values at the given row.

In C#, I would have written this:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetRow (int row)
{
    return Enumerable
        .Range (0, this.columns)
        .Select ((column) => this.grid[row, columns]);
}
```

or alternatively

```
IEnumerable<T> GetRow (int row)
{
    for (var column = 0; column < this.columns; column++) {
        yield return this.grid[row, column];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this in Swift though.

`Sequence` seems to be the equivalent to `IEnumerable<T>` but I don't understand why it uses `typealias` instead of just being defined as `Sequence<T>` ([see also this](https://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/playing-with-swift/2/)). Defining a method that returns generic `Sequence<T>` did not work:

```
extension Matrix {
    // Cannot specialize non-generic type 'Sequence'
    func getRow<T>(index: Int) -> Sequence<T> {
        return map(0..self.columns, { self[index, $0] })
    }
}
```

Then I got rid of `<T>` (but how is it supposed to be generic?):

```
extension Matrix {
    func getRow(index: Int) -> Sequence {
        return map(0..self.columns, { self[index, $0] })
    }
}
```

This compiles! However I can't use it:

```
var row = grid.getRow(0)
// 'Sequence' does not conform to protocol '_Sequence_'
for i in row {
    println("\(i)")
}
```

How do I properly type `map` result so it can be consumed in a `for..in` loop?

More on this issue: [Associated Type Considered Weird](http://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/associated-types-considered-weird/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Joe Groff [suggested](https://devforums.apple.com/message/981804#981804) to wrap the result in `SequenceOf<T>`:

```
extension Matrix {
    func getRow(index: Int) -> SequenceOf<T> {
        return SequenceOf(map(0..self.columns, { self[index, $0] }))
    }
}
```

Indeed, this works but we had to wrap `map` result into a helper class which differs from how I do it in C#.

I have to admit I don't yet understand why `Sequence` and `Generator` use `typealias` and aren't generic protocols (like `IEnumerable<T>` in C#).  There is an interesting ongoing discussion about this distinction so I'll leave a few links for a curious mind:

1. [Associated Types Considered Weird](http://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/associated-types-considered-weird/)
2. [Associated types vs. type parameters - reason for the former?](https://devforums.apple.com/message/983492#983492)
3. [Abstract Type Members versus Generic Type Parameters in Scala](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=270195)
4. [Generics and protocols](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swift-language/3PtydRXR0ao)

Comment: Don't forget that SequenceOf was removed from recent versions of Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are being mislead by the Swift compiler (which is a bit flaky at the moment). The type for your range `0..self.columns` is `Range<Int>`, which is not a `Sequence` or `Collection`, so I don't think it can be used via `map`.

The implementation works for me:

```
extension Matrix {
  func getRow(index: Int) -> T[] {
    var row = T[]()
    for col in 0..self.columns {
      row.append(self[index, col])
    }
    return row
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll file a radar... How do I keep the sequence lazy though?

Comment: @Dan are they lazy? If I perform a map on an array but do not do anything with the results the closure is still executed for all array values.

Comment: Weird! I thought that, if it doesn't return an array, then it has to be lazy. I'll check that.

Comment: Turns out we needed to use `SequenceOf`. See my update.