# Finding all combinations in an array (Swift 5) with enumeration

Tags: arrays, swift, find, combinations, enumeration

I have some code in C# that does exactly what I like to do: Enumerate all combinations of a given length in an array (with repetitions). Like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> CombinationsWithRepition(IEnumerable<int> input, int length)
{
    if (length <= 0)
        yield return new List<int>();
    else
    {
        foreach (int i in input)
            foreach (IEnumerable<int> c in CombinationsWithRepition(input, length - 1))
            {
                List<int> list = new List<int>();
                list.Add(i);
                list.AddRange(c);
                yield return list;
            }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (var c in CombinationsWithRepition(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 }, 2))
{
    foreach (var x in c)
        Console.Write(x + " : ");

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Output:

```
0 : 0
0 : 1
0 : 2
1 : 0
1 : 1
1 : 2
2 : 0
2 : 1
2 : 2
```

Now I want to port that to swift 5, but I failed. I searched the web but I can only find solutions without repetition or solutions that creates a huge array. It is important to have the ability to enumerate the whole thing (no output as an array or a list containing all results). I don't know how to port "yield" to swift code.

This is the closest I have found:
[How do I return a sequence in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137062/how-do-i-return-a-sequence-in-swift)

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Combinatorics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift does not have a `yield` statement. In order to enumerate all combinations “lazily” (without storing all combinations in an array) we have to implement a [`Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence) whose [`Iterator`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641120-iterator) computes the combinations on demand in its [`next()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/iteratorprotocol/1641682-next) method.

Here is a possible implementation. The idea is to maintain an array of “positions” as state variable. Initially it is

```
 [ base.startIndex, ..., base.startIndex ]
```

where `base` is the collection (e.g. `Array`) from which the combinations are build. In each iteration, the last position is incremented. If it reaches `base.endIndex` then it is reset to `base.startIndex`, and the next position is incremented. (This is exactly how you would increment a number in a number system, e.g. a decimal number.) If the first position has been incremented up to `base.endIndex` then the enumeration is done.

In each iteration, this `positions` array is mapped to the corresponding array of elements from the base collection and returned from the `next()` method.

Only this array and two boolean variables are needed as intermediate storage. The implementation uses ideas from [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/159375/35991) on Code Review, such as having only a single exit point in the `next()` method.

```
struct CombinationsWithRepetition<C: Collection> : Sequence {

    let base: C
    let length: Int

    init(of base: C, length: Int) {
        self.base = base
        self.length = length
    }

    struct Iterator : IteratorProtocol {
        let base: C

        var firstIteration = true
        var finished: Bool
        var positions: [C.Index]

        init(of base: C, length: Int) {
            self.base = base
            finished = base.isEmpty
            positions = Array(repeating: base.startIndex, count: length)
        }

        mutating func next() -> [C.Element]? {
            if firstIteration {
                firstIteration = false
            } else {
                // Update indices for next combination.
                finished = true
                for i in positions.indices.reversed() {
                    base.formIndex(after: &positions[i])
                    if positions[i] != base.endIndex {
                        finished = false
                        break
                    } else {
                        positions[i] = base.startIndex
                    }
                }

            }
            return finished ? nil : positions.map { base[$0] }
        }
    }

    func makeIterator() -> Iterator {
        return Iterator(of: base, length: length)
    }
}
```

Example 1:

```
let comb = CombinationsWithRepetition(of: [0, 1, 3], length: 2)
for c in comb { print(c) }
```

Output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[0, 3]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 3]
[3, 0]
[3, 1]
[3, 3]
```

Example 2:

```
let comb = CombinationsWithRepetition(of: "abcd", length: 3)
for c in comb { print(c) }
```

Output:

```
["a", "a", "a"]
["a", "a", "b"]
["a", "a", "c"]
["a", "a", "d"]
["a", "b", "a"]
...
["d", "d", "c"]
["d", "d", "d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to achieve what you wanted:

```swift
let source = Array((0...5))
let length = 3

func combinationsWithRepetition(input source: [Int], length: Int) -> [[Int]] {
  if length == 0 { return [[]] }
  let baseArray = combinationsWithRepetition(input: source, length: length - 1)
  var newArray = [[Int]]()
  for value in source {
    baseArray.forEach {
      newArray.append($0 + [value])
    }
  }
  return newArray
}

print(combinationsWithRepetition(input: [0, 1, 2], length: 2))
// [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

Or to be more functional:

```
func combinationsWithRepetition(input source: [Int], length: Int) -> [[Int]] {
  if length == 0 { return [[]] }
  let baseArray = combinationsWithRepetition(input: source, length: length - 1)
  return baseArray.flatMap { array in
    return source.map { array + [$0] }
  }
}
```

Basically, `combinationsWithRepetition` returns an array of all possible arrays of a combination of `length` elements.
For instance, `combinationsWithRepetition(input: [0, 1, 2, 3], length: 1)` returns `[[0], [1], [2], [3]]`.
`length` of more than 0 are handled using a recursion, which your originally seems to use (probably, since I don't know C# syntax).
Swift supports array addition, e.g., `[1] + [2]` is `[1, 2]`, and the above code is doing that for all values from `source` to the elements (which are possible combinations of length `length - 1`) of the resulting array.

The second code uses `flatMap` which "flattens" a nested array into an array, e.g. `[[[1, 2], [1, 3]], [[1, 4], [1, 5]]]` into `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5]]`.
Otherwise the logic is exactly identical with the one using an iteration.

To get the output as in your post, you can do:

```swift
combinationsWithRepetition(input: [0, 1, 2], length: 2).forEach {
  print($0.map(String.init).joined(separator: " : "))
}
```

which results in

```
0 : 0
0 : 1
0 : 2
1 : 0
1 : 1
1 : 2
2 : 0
2 : 1
2 : 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In languages that have `yield`, it is a call back to the calling function returning a result.  The state of the current function is maintained and continues when the `yield` returns.

We can implement something like that in Swift with a *closure* callback.

This is a nearly direct translation of your routine:

```
func combinationsWithRepetition(_ input: [Int], length: Int, yield: ([Int]) -> ()) {
    if length <= 0 {
        yield([])
    }
    else {
        for i in input {
            combinationsWithRepetition(input, length: length - 1) { c in
                var list = [Int]()
                list.append(i)
                list += c
                yield(list)
            }
        }
    }
}

combinationsWithRepetition([0, 1, 2], length: 2) { c in
    print(c.map(String.init).joined(separator: " : "))
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> 0 : 0
> 0 : 1
> 0 : 2
> 1 : 0
> 1 : 1
> 1 : 2
> 2 : 0
> 2 : 1
> 2 : 2
> ```

---

There are times when the caller wants to control the function that is *yielding*.  If you'd like to be able to stop the function, you can have the `yield` callback return a `Bool` telling the yielding function if it should continue.

Consider this example:

```
// Generate squares until told to stop
func squares(_ yield: (_ n: Int) -> Bool) {
    var i = 1
    var run = true
    while run {
        run = yield(i * i)
        i += 1
    }
}

// print squares until they exceed 200
squares() { n -> Bool in
    print(n)
    return n < 200
}
```

> ```
> 1
> 4
> 9
> 16
> 25
> 36
> 49
> 64
> 81
> 100
> 121
> 144
> 169
> 196
> 225
> ```