# Can I assign a default type to generic type T in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a generic class that I want to be able to use with a default type. Right now I can initialize it with any type, but I have to be explicit.

```
//Initialize with a type
MyManager<MyCustomerObject>()

// Initialize with NSObject (what I want to be my default type)
MyManager<NSObject>()

// This doesn't work, but I want this kind of functionality
class MyManager<T = NSObject> {}

// So I can create my manager like so and it inserts the default type as NSObject
MyManager() //Or MyManager<>()
```

Is this possible in Swift?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There's no support for default generic arguments, but you can fake it by defining the default `init()` on a type-constrained extension, in which case the compiler will be smart enough to use that type. E.g.:

```swift
class MyManager<T> {
    let instance: T

    init(instance: T) {
        self.instance = instance
    }
}

extension MyManager where T == NSObject {
    convenience init() {
        self.init(instance: NSObject())
    }
}
```

And now you can initialize the type with no argument and it will default to `MyManager<NSObject>`:

```swift
let mm1 = MyManager(instance: "Foo") // MyManager<String>
let mm2 = MyManager(instance: 1) // MyManager<Int>
let mm3 = MyManager() // MyManager<NSObject>
```

SwiftUI uses this technique quite a lot.

Comment: I have been racking my brain trying to figure out how SwiftUI did this, thanks so much. I really hope in the future Swift implements some sort of `init() where T==NSObject` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's hard to wrap my head around why it works. But I guess the compiler has a fallback to look at the first type constrained extension before complaining that it can't figure it out. Wish there was a simpler way to provide a default generic type especially when you are working with optionals and might not have a type.

Answer (score 37):

No, this currently isn't possible – although it is a [part of the Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#default-generic-arguments), so might be something that the Swift team will consider for a future version of the language.

> #### Default generic arguments
>
> Generic parameters could be given the ability to provide default
>   arguments, which would be used in cases where the type argument is not
>   specified and type inference could not determine the type argument.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> public final class Promise<Value, Reason=Error> { ... }
>
> func getRandomPromise() -> Promise<Int, Error> { ... }
>
> var p1: Promise<Int> = ... 
> var p2: Promise<Int, Error> = p1     // okay: p1 and p2 have the same type Promise<Int, Error>
> var p3: Promise = getRandomPromise() // p3 has type Promise<Int, Error> due to type inference
> ```

In the meantime however, a somewhat unsatisfactory compromise would be the use of a `typealias`:

```
class MyManager<T> {}

typealias MyManagerDefault = MyManager<NSObject>

let defaultManager = MyManagerDefault()
```

Not nearly as slick as just being able to say `MyManager()`, but it does show up next to `MyManager` in auto-complete, which is pretty handy.

Answer (score 2):

If `T` is always a `NSObject` subclass, you can use a generic constraint in Swift 5.3:

```
class MyManager<T: NSObject> {
    let t = T()
}

class MyCustomerObject: NSObject { }

let a = MyManager()
let b = MyManager<MyCustomerObject>()
```