# Generic function parameter default value

Tags: swift, generics

I am working with [swift-snapshot-testing](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing) and found a problem about Generic function parameter default value.

The framework provide a method like this:

```
func verifySnapshot<Value, Format>(matching value: Value,
                                   as snapshotting: Snapshotting<Value, Format>,
                                   snapshotDirectory: String? = nil) -> String?
```

where `Snapshotting` is a generic struct like this:

```
struct Snapshotting<Value, Format> {}

extension Snapshotting where Value == UIViewController, Format == UIImage {
    static var image: Snapshotting<UIViewController, UIImage> {
      :
    }
}

extension Snapshotting where Value == UIView, Format == UIImage {
    static var image: Snapshotting<UIView, UIImage> {
      :
    }
}
```

I want to create a helper method and this works:

```
func verify<Value, Format>(matching value: Value,
                           as snapshotting: Snapshotting<Value, Format>) {
    let snapshotDirectory = "/path"

    let failure = verifySnapshot(matching: value,
                                 as: snapshotting,
                                 snapshotDirectory: snapshotDirectory)

    print(failure ?? "Done!")
}
```

But when I want to give `snapshotting` a default parameter value `.image`, it does not compile for the error `Ambiguous reference to member 'image'`

```
func verify<Value, Format>(matching value: Value,
                           as snapshotting: Snapshotting<Value, Format> = Snapshotting<Value, Format>.image)
```

My question is: can Swift infer the generic type `Format` for default parameter value?

Comment: This question is related to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015081/can-i-assign-a-default-type-to-generic-type-t-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that `.image` does not exist for every `<Value, Format>` pair. It only exists for `<UIViewController, UIImage>`, and `<UIView, UIImage>`. To assign a default here, it has to be applicable to every way that `verify` can be called.

Default parameters can always be expressed as a separate function with fewer parameters, so you just need to add the desired overloads rather than the default value.

```
func verify(matching value: UIViewController) {
    verify(matching: value, as: .image)
}

func verify(matching value: UIView) {
    verify(matching: value, as: .image)
}
```

Comment: I have several alternatives: give up default parameter, refactor as your suggest and create a new `enum` as parameter. But I am still thinking about any "generic" solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ref to @Rob Napler's answer I made a work-round to make the interface looks like with default value:

```
///interface to accept snapshotting argument 
func verify<Value, Format>(matching value: Value,
                           as snapshotting: Snapshotting<Value, Format>)

///interfaces to accept specific kind of value 
func verify(matching value: UIView)
func verify(matching value: UIViewController)
:
:
```

and we can call it like

```
verify(matching: aView)
```

or

```
verify(matching: aView, as: .image)
```