# Default argument value of type 'JSONEncoder' cannot be converted to type 'Encoder' (TopLevelEncoder)

Tags: swift, generics, dependency-injection, combine

I tried to make a generic method that takes in a `TopLevelEncoder` and a `TopLevelDecoder` in order to make it injectable (eg. `JSONEncoder` in production code and `CustomEncoder` for testing). Since both of the protocols have associated types I have constraint their type rather than just doing `encoder: TopLevelEncoder = JSONEncoder()`. I came up with this method:

```
func test<Encoder, Decoder>(
    encoder: Encoder = JSONEncoder(),
    decoder: Decoder = JSONDecoder()
) where Encoder: TopLevelEncoder, Decoder: TopLevelDecoder {
    //encode and decode
}
```

The compiler gives me following error message: `Default argument value of type 'JSONEncoder' cannot be converted to type 'Encoder'`. I don't understand how it can not be converted to type `Encoder` since `JSONEncoder` inherits from `TopLevelEncoder`.

I might be misunderstanding how generics and `associatedType` work but I can't wrap my head around this error message either. Could someone help me out?

I have seen other approaches for this problem like creating a new protocol like `AnyEncoder` and extend `JSONEncoder` with it. But in my opinion it would just be cleaner to use the existing protocol. Also my method requires a `TopLevelDecoder` since I am using the `URLSessions`s `.dataTaskPublisher` (`.decode(...)`).

Comment: @Kamran that code is in Combine framework

Comment: It is not possible for now to have default values for generics, use custom protocol. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#default-generic-arguments

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42015159/4687211

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how safe it is to force cast in this situation, but this seems to compile and work:

```
struct User: Codable {
    var name: String
}

func decodeEncode<Encoder, Decoder>(
  encoder: Encoder = JSONEncoder() as! Encoder, 
  decoder: Decoder = JSONDecoder() as! Decoder) 
  where Encoder: TopLevelEncoder, Decoder: TopLevelDecoder, 
        Encoder.Output == Data, Decoder.Input == Data
{
    let bruceData = try! encoder.encode(User(name: "Bruce Lee"))
    let bruce = try! decoder.decode(User.self, from: bruceData)

    print("bruce: \(bruce)")
}

decodeEncode(encoder: JSONEncoder(), decoder: JSONDecoder())
```

It's possible to constraint `Encoder.Output == Decoder.Input` but I've explicitly specified `Data` because `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` both work with `Data`.