# Why can't I use a Color as a ShapeStyle?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swiftui

I was trying to create a default initialiser which initialises a variable called `shapeStyle` to `Color.black`. However, it kept throwing this error: Cannot assign value of type 'Color' to type 'T'

This is the code:

```
struct BorderStyle<T: ShapeStyle> {
    var shapeStyle: T
    var strokeStyle: StrokeStyle
    
    init() {
        self.shapeStyle = Color.black  // Cannot assign value of type 'Color' to type 'T'
        self.strokeStyle = StrokeStyle()
    }
    init(shapeStyle: T, strokeStyle: StrokeStyle) {
        self.shapeStyle = shapeStyle
        self.strokeStyle = strokeStyle
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Why can't I use `Color.black` here? 
(I'm certain `Color` conforms to `ShapeStyle`)

Comment: Why are you certain that `Color` conforms to `ShapeStyle`?

Comment: @Alladinian https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color

Comment: @mag_zbc When this question got closed as duplicate, did you notice [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59506860/4642212) there being automatically “thanks”-reacted by you without you doing it manually?