# Swift default value for generic enum

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums

I've an Enum with generic type like this:

```
public enum ServiceError<FailureResponse: Decodable>: Swift.Error {
    case other(Error)
    case underlying(statusCode: Int, response: URLResponse)
    case decodeError(error: FailureResponse?)
}
```

Can i set a default type to `FailureResponse`? if I could do that, whoever uses my library would not be forced to pass the generic type

Comment: I think the only way is using a `typealias`, but you would not be able to use the `ServiceError` enum name.

Comment: mmm...can i show me it?

Comment: For example: `typealias DefaultServiceError = ServiceError<MyCustomDecodable>` where `MyCustomDecodable` is your default FailureResponse decodable

Comment: What default type do you want `FailureResponse` to be? Note that `Decodable` is not an option (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42015159/9188735

Comment: mmm...typealias isn't the answer. My is an external library. The typealias remains at external. Correct?

Comment: @nunziogiuliocaggegi typealias is probably not the best solution. About being external, I believe you're talking about the visibility, right? The visibility works like any other structure